# AWS ElasticBeanstalk EC2 to RDS postgresql connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3

Not able to connect to RDS PostgreSQL 9.3 database from EC2 (elastic-beanstalk). Environment was created using the Elastic Beanstalk v3 CLI with PostgreSQL 9.3.5, Puma (Ruby 2.1), Rails 4.1.6. postgresql93-devel was successfully installed by yum through .ebextensions/postgres.config:

```
packages:
  yum:
     postgresql93-devel: []
```

SECRET_KEY_BASE has been added to Environment table through console.

Getting the following error on rake db:migrate during eb deploy:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_DATABSE, RDS_USER_NAME, RDS_PASSWORD: all verified in rails console by ssh'ing to ec2 box.

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  hostname: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have mistakenly written **hostname** instead of **host** in database.yml